# Forming text based on values from table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am currently working on a import and need to build a comma delimited string based on the values a table row. Iam able to do it this way but want to know if i can optimize this.

```
      If((Select planValue from #tempTable) = 'Yes')
      Begin
       SET @ltValue='1'
      END

      If((Select planValue1 from #tempTable) = 'Yes')
      Begin
          IF(LEN(@ltValue) > 0)
           BEGIN
               SET @ltValue=@ltValue+',2'
           END
           ELSE
           BEGIN
               SET @ltValue='2'
           END         
      END

      If((Select planValue2 from #tempTable) = 'Yes')
      Begin
          IF(LEN(@ltValue) > 0)
           BEGIN
               SET @ltValue=@ltValue+',3'
           END
           ELSE
           BEGIN
               SET @ltValue='3'
           END         
      END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An issue with your provided solution is if there are more than one row in the temp table.  Here is an option that creates the string within a select.

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE (
    planValue varchar(5),
    planValue1 varchar(5),
    planValue2 varchar(5)
    )

insert @tmpTable (planValue, planValue1, PlanValue2) VALUES ('Yes', 'Yes', 'No')
insert @tmpTable (planValue, planValue1, PlanValue2) VALUES ('Yes', 'No', 'No')
INSERT @tmpTable (planValue, planValue1, PlanValue2) VALUES ('No', 'Yes', 'Yes')
INSERT @tmpTable (planValue, planValue1, PlanValue2) VALUES ('No', 'No', 'Yes')
INSERT @tmpTable (planValue, planValue1, PlanValue2) VALUES ('Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes')

select REPLACE(REPLACE(CASE WHEN planValue = 'Yes' THEN '1|' ELSE '' END +  
                CASE WHEN planValue1 = 'Yes' THEN '|2|' ELSE '' END + 
                CASE WHEN planValue2 = 'Yes' THEN '|3|' ELSE '' END, '||', ','), '|', '') [ResultData]
FROM @tmpTable
```

OUTPUT

```
ResultData
1,2
1
2,3
3
1,2,3
```

The case statements add in the necessary values with a unique delimiter.  The inner replace finds two consecutive delimiters and changes it to a comma.  The last outer replace finds a single delimiter and removes it.